# I do not break unless

Tags: riddle

I do not break if thrown from the highest building
I do not break if you stamp on me
I will break if touched by water 
Who Am I?

Comment: This seems too broad. Any molecule which dissolves in water would work.

Comment: Paper, tissues, salt, sugar, all of these answers fit the description, so I agree with Jens.

Comment: @Jens I am really sorry. I will keep in mind the broad range of answers possible next time.

Comment: @Duck The answer I expected was tissues but now sugar may also work and then there's paper, salt, and any water soluble substance.

Comment: In general, a very *short* riddle is more likely to have many possible answers. A short riddle might have a unique answer, but usually involving some fancy wordplay rather than just description like this. The more different clues you have, the narrower the possible scope of solutions will be. Just some advice for next time :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are:

> Paper.

I do not break if thrown from the highest building

> Nope. Also, this works if you make a paper airplane.

I do not break if you stamp on me

> It's flat!

I will break if touched by water

> Water reduces paper to a pulp.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could be:

> A single grain of salt

I do not break if thrown from the highest building

> A grain of salt, due to its small size, would not break into smaller pieces if thrown from a great height.

I do not break if you stamp on me

> I took a single grain of salt from my salt shaker and was unable to break it by stamping on it.

I will break if touched by water

> A grain of salt will dissolve (break up) if touched by even a small amount of water.

...and by this logic

> you're also a grain of sugar, or any other granular solids which dissolve in water

Answer (score 2):

This riddle might be too broad. One answer which fits is

> dryness.

Because

> you can throw something dry off a building, or stamp on it, and it will still be dry, but if water touches it it won't be dry any more.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are

> An envelope

I do not break if thrown from the highest building

> An envelope will just float down.

I do not break if you stamp on me

> Putting a stamp on the envelope will not damage it, rather the
>  opposite

I will break if touched by water

> A sealed envelope will break open if touched by water in the form of
>  steam.